# Same CSS style formatting differently based on pattern

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to define a style that assigns one set of formatting rules for non-parenthesized text and another for parenthesized?  The reason for this is to avoid cluttering of format tags (like `<b>` or `<span>`). E.g if I have something like

`<B>Item1</B> (expl), <B>Item2</B> (expl2), ..., <B>ItemN</B> (explN)`

It would be cleaner to state it as

`<span class="myClass">Item1 (expl), Item2 (expl2), ..., ItemN (explN)</span>`

Where `myClass` is defined as formatting parenthesized text under a set of rules different from non-parenthesized (bolding non-parenthesized in this example).

Comment: Is there no server side script generating this HTML/CSS?

Comment: no, assume static HTML.  but even if there were one, the HTML would be more minimalist if this contingent processing were possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this can't be done in HTML/CSS but can be achieved by using Javascript. Once the page is loaded (onLoad), you can scan for items (may be using a regex) and then surround the text with custom tags.